# when use pre-commit, mypy check passed but print mypy syntax error

Tags: git, mypy, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit.com

I use pre-commit to run mypy type check, and when mypy check passed it print string error logs like this.

```
/username/.cache/pre-commit/repo61b8m7wl/py_env-python3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mypy/typeshed/stdlib/2and3/builtins.pyi:33: error: syntax error in type comment
```

this is very annoying because similar logs printed like 20 lines or 30 lines and it is not even related to code that I wrote. How can I disable this?

this is my pre-commit config file.

```
repos:
  
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
    rev: v0.720
    hooks:
     - id: mypy
       verbose: true
       entry: bash -c 'mypy "$@" || true' --
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`|| true` ignores any error from `mypy`. Remove it:

```
   entry: bash -c 'mypy "$@"' --
```

or simply

```
   entry: mypy
```